# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I cannot figure out why as soon as I try to use the [mainArray addObject:] expression my whole program fails! If i pass it strings it works just fine, but as soon as i try to pass it a variable it fails, any help?

```
#import "AG_ViewController.h"
#import "AG_Storage.h"
#import "AG_AddItemViewController.h"

@interface AG_ViewController ()



@end

@implementation AG_ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mainArray = [NSMutableArray array];


    AG_Storage *item1 = [[AG_Storage alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = @"Test";

    NSLog(@"Add item1");
    NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);

    AG_Storage *item2 = [[AG_Storage alloc] init];
    item2.itemName = @"Test2";


    NSLog(@"Add item2");
    [mainArray addObject:item1];
    NSLog(@"%@", mainArray);

     }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [mainArray count]; }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewer cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewer dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

@end
```

I initialized mainArray in the header file,

```
@interface AG_ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

NSMutableArray *mainArray;
```

}

Log is as follows:

```
2014-03-18 13:49:26.028 AgendaBk[22575:a0b] Add item1
2014-03-18 13:49:26.030 AgendaBk[22575:a0b] (
)
2014-03-18 13:49:26.030 AgendaBk[22575:a0b] Add item2
2014-03-18 13:49:26.031 AgendaBk[22575:a0b] (
    "<AG_Storage: 0x895bdc0>"
)
2014-03-18 13:49:26.036 AgendaBk[22575:a0b] -[AG_Storage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x895bdc0
2014-03-18 13:49:26.039 AgendaBk[22575:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AG_Storage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

*Junk here*

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the complete and exact message.

Comment: BTW - do you really want to store an array of your two objects in `mainArray`? It would seem to make more sense to add the two items individually to `mainArray`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify this well. In my header file i did this to initialize mainArray

     
@interface AG_ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    
    NSMutableArray *mainArray;

}

Comment: Again, could you add the whole error message?

Comment: Yeah just did. I updated the code a bit, i should just be able to do [mainArray addObject:item] right? I think the issue may lie in AG_Storage

Comment: Your code is calling `length` on `AG_Storage` after the objects have been added to the array, that is where the crash is occurring because `AG_Storage` does not have a selector `length`.

Comment: So how do I get it to not call `length`? I'm a little confused haha, Also i'm going to need to add information to `mainArray` later, which is why i'm using a mutable array in the first place. I didn't have this problem before i tried using `UITableView`, `UITableViewController` worked fine with this code. I'm just gonna go ahead and post the entire code, just to make sure its not something in another method.

Comment: Never mind i took care of it! I figured out what i was doing wrong, i wasn't configuring my cell correctly and had the program all confused looking for data in AG_Storage. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Note (you probably don't actually have it in your code, but anyway): Don't forget `NSMutableArray *mainArray = [NSMutableArray array]`

Try to use `[mainArray addObjectsFromArray:@[item1, item2]];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       NSMutableArray *mainArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        AG_Storage *item1 = [[AG_Storage alloc] init];
        item1.itemName = @"Test";
        NSLog(@"Add item1");
        NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);

        AG_Storage *item2 = [[AG_Storage alloc] init];
        item2.itemName = @"Test2";
        NSLog(@"Add item2");
        [mainArray addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: item1, item2, nil]];
        NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);


    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't quite understand the difference between an instance variable and a local variable. If your first code version compiled and you haven't changed your properties, then your first example assigned an NSMutableArray* to an instance variable, where it stays until that view is deallocated, while the second example assigned an NSMutableArray* to a local variable, where ARC will deallocate it as soon as the method returns. item1 and item2 will disappear as well.

It is highly recommended to start instance variables with an underscore (like _mainArray), to make it more obvious what you are doing.

Sorry, just noticed that it was someone else changing the instance variable to a local variable.